# Google API Future Prediction of Traffic = Typical Traffic shown on Google Maps (maps.google.com)

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-distancematrix-api

I just wanted to ask if the future traffic information given in the Google API (Google Distance Matrix API to be exact) is the same as the traffic data used in the typical traffic overlay in the Google maps app. Aren't they both based on historical data, and thus, should be similar if not the same?

Thank you and I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, so long as you don't specific `traffic_model` other than `best_guess`.

They  both use historical traffic data to predict "likely" traffic conditions in the near future, based on time of day and day of week. However, your API requests may not always carry the exact same meaning as your input on Google Maps, so there may be cases where each return slightly different results. Should you find big differences, please [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:DirectionsAPI%20type:Defect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars).